# how to access records in on of the two many to many tables that isn't in the third junction table?

Tags: sql, web2py

For a many to many relationship being possible, a third table is created in the normalization process which serves as a junction table that defines the many to many relationship.

Now i have two tables one called "matter" and the other is "user" then i have a third junction table for these two called "matter_user" that has references both the "matter" and the "user" table.
My problem is how do i assign a user to a matter so that that user goes off the unassigned list for that specific matter yet it can show up in case am assigning a user to a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be over-complicating this in your head.

- You've got a User table.  It has the users and their info.
- You've got a Matter table.  It has... matters, and their info.
- You've got a Matter_User table.  It simply has two columns: a UserID
  and a MatterID.

So how do you assign a user to a matter?  You simply add the MatterID and UserID into a new row in that third table.

> "But what if they're already there?"

You can always simply check if that entry is already in the third table before adding it.

> "But what if I want to get the list of Matters that the User isn't
>   already assigned to?  For a combo list or something?"

Then query the Matter table, and put one of its where clauses that the MatterID isn't in

```
    Select MatterID from Combined where UserID = @UserGettingListFor
```

... aka, "Show me all Matters where the MatterID isn't already in the combined table under the particular UserID I care about.

Make sense?

Comment: thank you and Yes this surely makes sense and i actually buy it but, its a long way to the goal or even perhaps i may never get my goal. Her is some more explanation, I matter i have selected in my browser so i pass its id as an argument to another page that has all users, so i get the user id i wanna add to this matter, i add it, so now i want to refresh the page with this list of users unassigned  for this specific matter, in otherward when i refresh, the last user i assigned should never appear on my list, this is how i did it

Comment: `'select id,first_name,last_name from auth_user au where role="client" and au.id not in (select mu.auth_user_id from matter_user mu where mu.lpm_case_id=%s)'% matter_id`